Show column header when there is no data interactive grid
the title says it all, I would like to be able to show the column headers when there is no data. I know this is possible with interactive grid, but is this possible to do in interactive report as well in any of the newer apex versions? Maybeby adding any javascript or other tricks?
Thanks in advance

Not as far as I know. You could use a read only interactive grid instead of an interactive report.

Does this answer your question? Show header when no data in interactive report oracle apex

@Oguen i have seen that but since it was 4 years old, i had hoped the answer would be different by now :-)

well, fair enough :)
